# Create custom layer control for Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to create a custom leaflet layer control for making layers visible or hidden. I created a html div which has a checkbox to hide or make visible a layer.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="layer1" name="Layer1"><label for="layer1"> LAYER 1</label><br>
```

I have created an example leaflet layer

```
var OpenRailwayMap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.openrailwaymap.org/standard/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://www.OpenRailwayMap.org">OpenRailwayMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
    });
```

The problem I have now is how to use JavaScript to mark on the checkbox to show or hide the layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using `oninput` event handler for checkbox input element and `.hasLayer`, `.addLayer` and `.removeLayer` Leaflet map methods.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="layer1" name="Layer1" oninput="toggleLayer(this)"><label for="layer1"> LAYER 1 </label>
```

**JS**

```
function toggleLayer(element) {
  if (element.checked) {
    if (!map.hasLayer(OpenRailwayMap)) map.addLayer(OpenRailwayMap);
    }
  else {
    if (map.hasLayer(OpenRailwayMap)) map.removeLayer(OpenRailwayMap);
  }
}
document.getElementById('layer1').checked = map.hasLayer(OpenRailwayMap);
```

Comment: Worked as I wanted. Trying understand all the pieces (I am new to JS). I understand how the code works. The html runs the JS function. The JS function checks and adds or removes the layer. I don't understand what the last line does. I commented it out and the code still runs. Could you shed some light on it?

Comment: Last line sets the value of the input checkbox to reflect the actual status of `OpenRailwayMap` layer: is it added to the map or not.